# Convergence or divergence of $\int_0^a \frac{\cos \frac{1}{x}}{x \sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I want to check if the following integral exists: $$\int_0^a \frac{\cos \frac{1}{x}}{x \sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx$$

I tried to bound it from above by a converging integral with no success. Any hint?

Comment: Let $t=1/x$, and you will get some Fresnel type integral, which converges.

Comment: For $a\to\infty$, the integral converges to $\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a>0$. You may write, by the change of variable $u=1/x$ and an integration by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^a\frac{\cos \frac1x}{x\sqrt{x}}\:dx&=\int_{1/a}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{u}}\:du\\\\
&=\left.\frac{\sin u}{\sqrt{u}}\right|_{1/a}^{\infty}+\frac12\int_{1/a}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/2}}\:du\\\\
&=-\sqrt{a}\sin (1/a)+\frac12\int_{1/a}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/2}}\:du
\end{align}
$$  giving
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^a\frac{\cos \frac1x}{x\sqrt{x}}\:dx\right|\leq\left|\sqrt{a}\sin (1/a)\right|+\frac12\int_{1/a}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{u^{3/2}}\:du=\left|\sqrt{a}\sin (1/a)\right|+\sqrt{a}<+\infty
\end{align} 
$$ thus the **convergence** of the initial integral.

Comment: why you put at the final $< \infty$ ? what you want to put in evidence?